# Django split Models in différents models.py files give me import loops

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have splitted two models in two files :

**website.py**

```
class WebSite(models.Model):
    ...
    maintenance_page = ForeignKey(Page)
```

**page.py**

```
class Page(models.Model):
    ...
    website = ForeignKey(WebSite)
```

Of course I have a problem with the loop import.

What could I do ?
The simple thing is to combine the two classes in the same file but I cannot do that.

What else ?

Comment: Is there a reason that you have your models split out into different files, rather than having them all in a models.py file? Curious is all..

Comment: The code of this two models are quite big so I prefer to split them. And for some reason they are not in the same app.

Comment: Having two models depend on each other and not be in the same app? Bad bad bad design.

Comment: Actually they were not dependant before but with this change, they will be now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class WebSite(models.Model):
    ...
    maintenance_page = ForeignKey('app_name.Page')

class Page(models.Model):
    ...
    website = ForeignKey('app_name.WebSite')
```